# Static methods in model for getting data only: is it still bad? It is stateless anyway

Tags: php, oop

Seems reasonable at first to me, but when I searched for a reason why use it, it seems most people or answers I found tends to avoid it.

Say I have a method that just get something and only needs an `id` parameter. Is it still bad?

For example, I have a model and would like to do this: `User::getCompleteInfo($id)`

That's stateless and seems reasonable to use static on that one. Why bother creating an instance and then you'll just get something anyway?

But it's first time for `static` to come up in my mind which means **I never used it before** and just searched for why should I use it but instead found answers **why should not use it**. Any explanations if why that might be a bad idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods are easy to abuse, but the pattern you are suggesting is often something like `User::find($id)` or `User::findById($id)`, and sometimes people even make helpers such as `User::findByEmail($email)`. This pattern is fine for a case like this, but be careful not to abuse it.

Comment: seems like you know the worst cases. Please tell me when I might be already abusing it and how to avoid. I will really appreciate it. Already did my research about this but only find why it is bad.

Comment: When it becomes abusive often turns into a matter of preference. I guess the thing to keep in mind is if you are trying to use static methods as a new way of accessing things globally and tightly coupling your code to these static methods. Unfortunately, a lot of "knowing when" usually comes down to experience, asking peers for code review, and reading various books to help guide the way. A good start for now would be [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/), but that doesn't cover when (not) to use static methods.

Comment: Hmm, since it looks like I'll be just using the model in this particular controller that needs it, I guess it's not really coupling. Thanks btw. I'll wait for a few more answers before accepting yours